# Multiplying two attributes

Tags: php

I need to figure out how to calculate a workers weekly earning.  I need to do so by using a getWeeklyEarnings method, but cannot figure out how to multiply the two attributes wage and hours.

My questions are what would the code be in the class.php and how would I call it in the object.  Any advice would be amazing, Thank You!

Attached will be my code thus far. [My Class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyYNR.jpg)

Comment: Please post actual code instead of screenshots. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1402846) for details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Like what hanky-웃-panky said above, but make the function public instead.

```
public function getWeeklyEarnings()
{
    return $this->hours * $this->wage;
}
```

That way, you can call it in your provided code like:

```
echo "Weekly Earnings: $" . $w1->getWeeklyEarnings();
```

Alternatively, if you cannot edit `hourly_worker.class.php`, but can access the hours and wage of that class, then you could probably do something like:

```
echo "Weekly Earnings: $" . $w1->hours * $w1->wage;
```